# jquery.tokeninput required

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have this fantastic little plugin working but I need to require that at least one name be selected.  I normally use jquery.validate.  However, the validation plugin does not appear to work on a field using the tokeninput.  Does anyone have an answer?  As always, thanks so much for your help.

```
$("#NewMessage").validate({          
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        }
    }
}); 
   $("#name").tokenInput("lookup.cfc?method=getNames&returnFormat=json", {
  hintText: "Type in the name of recipient(s)",
  noResultsText: "No results",
  searchingText: "Searching..."
  })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it overriding ignore (apparently the problem is that tokenInput hides the original input and by default "validate" doesn't validate hidden inputs)

```
$("#NewMessage").validate({       
    ignore: "",   
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Laura, I've added another question regarding jQuery.tokenInput. Have you any experience with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341035/jquery-tokeninput-plugin-and-focus.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote and tried,It's working fine to me.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("autocomplete_check", function(value, element) {
       return ( value != '' ) ? true : false;  
   }, "");



    $("#NewMessage").validate({       
          ignore: "",   
          rules: {
            name: {
                autocomplete_check: true
            }
          },
          messages: {
               autocomplete_check: "Please fill the name"
          }
       });
```