# jQuery tokenInput plugin (and focus)

Tags: jquery-plugins

Is anyone using tokeninput plugin and successfully setting focus on a token input field? I'm trying to achieve [this](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/160).

Solved: 
In case anyone else needs, the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $("#YourTokenInput").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php", 
        { theme: "facebook" 
    }).focus(); 
});
```

Comment: In case anyone else needs, the solution: 
    $(document).ready(function() { $("#YourTokenInput").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php", { theme: "facebook" }).focus(); });

Answer (score 3):

OP's solution didn't work for me. Not sure if it is a browser issue, or a issue with the elements being loaded in time, or what, but this is what I had to do (after initializing the token input:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#token-input-search-input').focus(); }, 50);
```

Note: (testing in Chrome)