# How to Apply jQuery's Validation Engine validators to jQuery TokenInput

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validation-engine, jquery-tokeninput

I am Using TokenInput 1.6.0 in my asp.net project. I am using jQuery validation engine to apply validation. I am trying to apply validators to textbox which I am using as TokenInput and the code as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBLocation" runat="server" MaxLength="500" TextMode="MultiLine" TabIndex="17" CssClass="validate[required] text-input mandatory"></asp:TextBox>
```

But it's not working as I expected. So there is any way to apply validators to tokeninput textbox..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ignore` of validation plugin as tokeninput hides your original element like,

```
$("form").validate({       
    ignore: "",   
    ...
});
```

For more info [jquery.tokeninput required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811028/jquery-tokeninput-required)

Comment: Thanx for reply. I use the way u said and as per you provide me link. The code is as follows: 
$("#frmUser").validate({
        ignore: "",
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    }); But it is giving me as error - 'Undefined is not a function'

Comment: Check you have included validation plugin before using it.
Check you frmUser id exists.
Also, dont't use `name` if your input element has not any name(use required class in that case).

Comment: Actually I am not using Validation plugin and rest of the things like form id is correct. There is any way to apply validation by using validation engine validators?? instead of using validation plugin.